# Enter WPS Pin on Router from Android

Tags: android, sdk, router

How can i enter a WPS (Wifi protected Setup) Pin on a router programatically using Android SDK?? 
In addition can i get the responses that the router sends?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung has added this as a feature to some of their phones, but it is not a default feature of Android. That being said, I doubt that there is going to be a simple way of implementing this. Chances are you are going to have to learn about how the WPS protocol works and implement it yourself from scratch. This will involve broadcasting the correct signals over the WIFI, and performing the secure handshake with the router. I don't know much about how this works, you'll have to look up the WPS protocol.

There is a good chance that your app will require root access as you will need to alter WIFI network entries on the phone, and perhaps even add support for storing this information.